# PHP: POST JSON string - urlencode doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, json

When I try the following:

```
     $post_string='data='.urlencode(json_encode($data));  //data is a big nested array
     $post_string='&password='.urlencode($password);
     $post_string='&username='.urlencode($username);
```

The $_POST data I received on the other server becomes corrupted - either password or username is missing. I suspect I did not encode the data into JSON in the correct way. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `=` to assign a *new* value. Each line discards the previous value. You want to use `.=` for a **concatenating assignment**.

Comment: Err... what a shame. I thought I used .=. Can I delete this question in any way?